# How to make inputs disabled until button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want all inputs (radios, checkboxes, etc..) to be disabled (I don't want to be able to check them/ type) until "Start Quiz" button is clicked.

(That's all I need, this code is a quiz and I don't want people to be able to start doing it before clicking that button that releases starting time. But I don't know how to do it, I'm new to all this.)

```js
 var tacniOdgovori = 0;
 var netacniOdgovori = 0;
 function pocniKviz(){
  vreme1 = new Date();
  var vremeOd = vreme1.getHours() + ":" + vreme1.getMinutes() + ":" + vreme1.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("vremeOd").innerHTML = vremeOd;
  document.getElementById("btnZapocniKviz").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btnZavrsiKviz").disabled = false;
 }
 function zavrsiKviz(){
  var pitanje1 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje1');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje1.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje1[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje1[i].value == "Da"){
     tacniOdgovori = tacniOdgovori + 1;
    }
   }
  }
  var pitanje2 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje2');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje2.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje2[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje2[i].value == "HTTP"){
     tacniOdgovori++;
    }
   }
  }
  if(document.getElementById("pitanje3").value == "interakcija"){
   tacniOdgovori++;
  }
  var pitanje4 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje4');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje4.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje4[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje4[i].value == "Apache" && pitanje4[i].value == "IIS"){
     tacniOdgovori++;
    }
   }
   if (pitanje4[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje4[i].value == "Apache" || pitanje4[i].value == "IIS"){
     tacniOdgovori=tacniOdgovori+0.5;
    }
   }
   document.getElementById("btnResetujKviz").disabled = false;
  }
  vreme2 = new Date();
  var vremeDo = vreme2.getHours() + ":" + vreme2.getMinutes() + ":" + vreme2.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("vremeDo").innerHTML = vremeDo;
  document.getElementById("tacniOdgovori").innerHTML = tacniOdgovori;
  document.getElementById("netacniOdgovori").innerHTML = 4 - tacniOdgovori;
  document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = (tacniOdgovori/4)*100 + "%";
  document.getElementById("btnZavrsiKviz").disabled = true; 
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="padding:1%;">
 <h2 align="center">Kviz</h3>
 <button onclick="pocniKviz()" id="btnZapocniKviz">Start Quiz</button>
 <p>Vreme pocetka rada: <span id="vremeOd" style="color:red">span vreme od</span></p>
 <hr>
 <h3>1. Da li je moguce hostovati web sajt na vise web servera?</h3>
 <input type="radio" value="Da" name="pitanje1">Da</input>
 <input type="radio" value="Ne" name="pitanje1">Ne</input>
 <input type="radio" value="Svaki" name="pitanje1">Svaki web sajt se hostuje na vise web servera</input>
 <h3>2. Pomocu kojih protokola je moguce pristupiti sajtovima? (jedan ili vise odgovora)</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" value="FTP" name="pitanje2">FTP</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "HTTP" name="pitanje2">HTTP</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "SMB" name="pitanje2">SMB</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "SSH" name="pitanje2">SSH</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "WSP" name="pitanje2">WSP</input>
 <h3>3. Kada korisnik vrsi neku aktivnost na sajtu to se zove <input id="pitanje3"></h3>
 <h3>4. Sta je od navedenog web server? (jedan ili više odgovora)</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Apache" name="pitanje4">Apache</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Samba" name="pitanje4">Samba</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value="IIS" name="pitanje4">IIS</input>
 <hr>
 <button onclick="zavrsiKviz()" id="btnZavrsiKviz" disabled>Zavrsi kviz</button>
 <button onClick="window.location.reload()" id="btnResetujKviz" disabled>Resetuj kviz</button>
 <p>Vreme kraja rada: <font color="red"><span id="vremeDo">span vreme do</span></font></p>
 <p>Tacnih odgovora: <font color="green"><span id="tacniOdgovori">span tacnih odgovora</span></font></p>
 <p>Netacnih odgovora: <font color="red"><span id="netacniOdgovori">span netacnih odgovora</span></font></p>
 <p>Uspeh u procentima: <span id="rezultat">span rezultata</span></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a disabled property to your input elements and then
I implemented in some of the inputs

try to understand it and then do same thing with other inputs

**Main Part Changed**

put this code into your **start Quiz** button's click event

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // gets all the input tags as nodelist
var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(input); //convert it to array
inputList.forEach(function(element) { // loops through it and then sets disabled = false 
    element.disabled = false;
  });
```

```js
var tacniOdgovori = 0;
 var netacniOdgovori = 0;
 function pocniKviz(){
  vreme1 = new Date();
  var vremeOd = vreme1.getHours() + ":" + vreme1.getMinutes() + ":" + vreme1.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("vremeOd").innerHTML = vremeOd;
  document.getElementById("btnZapocniKviz").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btnZavrsiKviz").disabled = false;
    var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // gets all the input tags as nodelist
    var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(input); //convert it to array
    inputList.forEach(function(element) { // loops through it and then sets disabled = false 
      element.disabled = false;
     });
    
 }
 function zavrsiKviz(){
  var pitanje1 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje1');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje1.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje1[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje1[i].value == "Da"){
     tacniOdgovori = tacniOdgovori + 1;
    }
   }
  }
  var pitanje2 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje2');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje2.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje2[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje2[i].value == "HTTP"){
     tacniOdgovori++;
    }
   }
  }
  if(document.getElementById("pitanje3").value == "interakcija"){
   tacniOdgovori++;
  }
  var pitanje4 = document.getElementsByName('pitanje4');
  for (var i = 0; i < pitanje4.length; i++)
  {
   if (pitanje4[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje4[i].value == "Apache" && pitanje4[i].value == "IIS"){
     tacniOdgovori++;
    }
   }
   if (pitanje4[i].checked)
   {
    if(pitanje4[i].value == "Apache" || pitanje4[i].value == "IIS"){
     tacniOdgovori=tacniOdgovori+0.5;
    }
   }
   document.getElementById("btnResetujKviz").disabled = false;
  }
  vreme2 = new Date();
  var vremeDo = vreme2.getHours() + ":" + vreme2.getMinutes() + ":" + vreme2.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("vremeDo").innerHTML = vremeDo;
  document.getElementById("tacniOdgovori").innerHTML = tacniOdgovori;
  document.getElementById("netacniOdgovori").innerHTML = 4 - tacniOdgovori;
  document.getElementById("rezultat").innerHTML = (tacniOdgovori/4)*100 + "%";
  document.getElementById("btnZavrsiKviz").disabled = true; 
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="padding:1%;">
 <h2 align="center">Kviz</h3>
 <button onclick="pocniKviz()" id="btnZapocniKviz">Start Quizz</button>
 <p>Vreme pocetka rada: <span id="vremeOd" style="color:red">span vreme od</span></p>
 <hr>
 <h3>1. Da li je moguce hostovati web sajt na vise web servera?</h3>
 <input type="radio" value="Da" name="pitanje1" disabled>Da</input>
 <input type="radio" value="Ne" name="pitanje1" disabled>Ne</input>
 <input type="radio" value="Svaki" name="pitanje1" disabled>Svaki web sajt se hostuje na vise web servera</input>
 <h3>2. Pomocu kojih protokola je moguce pristupiti sajtovima? (jedan ili vise odgovora)</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" value="FTP" name="pitanje2" disabled>FTP</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "HTTP" name="pitanje2" disabled>HTTP</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "SMB" name="pitanje2" disabled>SMB</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "SSH" name="pitanje2" disabled>SSH</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value= "WSP" name="pitanje2" disabled>WSP</input>
 <h3>3. Kada korisnik vrsi neku aktivnost na sajtu to se zove <input id="pitanje3"></h3>
 <h3>4. Sta je od navedenog web server? (jedan ili više odgovora)</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Apache" name="pitanje4">Apache</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Samba" name="pitanje4">Samba</input>
 <input type="checkbox" value="IIS" name="pitanje4">IIS</input>
 <hr>
 <button onclick="zavrsiKviz()" id="btnZavrsiKviz" disabled>Zavrsi kviz</button>
 <button onClick="window.location.reload()" id="btnResetujKviz" disabled>Resetuj kviz</button>
 <p>Vreme kraja rada: <font color="red"><span id="vremeDo">span vreme do</span></font></p>
 <p>Tacnih odgovora: <font color="green"><span id="tacniOdgovori">span tacnih odgovora</span></font></p>
 <p>Netacnih odgovora: <font color="red"><span id="netacniOdgovori">span netacnih odgovora</span></font></p>
 <p>Uspeh u procentima: <span id="rezultat">span rezultata</span></p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it! Blessed be :)

Comment: I did, but my reputation is low, so it cant be seen :P

Answer (score 1):

First, add a `disabled` property to your `input` elements, like this

```
<input type="radio" value="Da" name="pitanje1" disabled="disabled">Da</input>
```

Then, inside your `pocniKviz()` function:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input'); //get all inputs and store into an array

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = false; //enable the element
}
```

you can also disable your inputs through `JS`, on the first line of your `script`:

```
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = true; //disable the element
}
```